# Subspace topology in the union of subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let $A,B$ and $C$ be subsets of a topological space $X$ with $C \subseteq A \cup B$. If $A,B$ and $A \cup B$ are given the subspace topology, prove that $C$ is open with respect to $A \cup B$ if and only if $C \cap A$ is open with respect to $A$ and $C \cap B$ is open with respect to $B$.

I already proved that if $C$ is open with respect to $A \cup B$ then $C \cap A$ is open with respect to $A$ and $C \cap B$ is open with respect to $B$. Just note that $C=G \cap (A \cup B)$ for some $G$ open in $X$; then $C=(G \cap A) \cup (G \cap B)$, so that $C \cap A = G \cap A$ and $C \cap B= G \cap B$.

I haven't been able to prove the converse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't prove the converse is that it is false! Take $A=[0,1]$, $B=(1,2]$ as subsets of $\mathbb R$. Then $C=A$ satisfies $C\cap A=A$ is open in $A$ and $C\cap B=\emptyset$ is open in $B$. But clearly $A$ is not open in $A\cup B=[0,2]$.

Comment: Thank you! great counterexample.